# how to remove a CGWindowID from CFArrayRef?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to remove a windowId from the CFArrayRef

```
CFArrayRef window2ids = CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly ,
                                           kCGNullWindowID);
```

Is that possible? If it is how to do that? I have googled but I didn't find any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  CFArrayRef window2ids = CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly ,
                                       kCGNullWindowID);
  NSMutableArray *mutArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(__bridge_transfer NSMutableArray *)window2ids];
  id windowIamLookingFor;
  [mutArray indexOfObject:windowIamLookingFor];
  [mutArray removeObject:yourWindowId];
  CFArrayRef window3ids = (__bridge CFArrayRef)[mutArray copy];
```

or do corefoundation dance

```
  CFArrayRef window2ids = CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly ,
                                         kCGNullWindowID);
  CFMutableArrayRef mutWindowsIds = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, window2ids);
  CFRelease(window2ids);
  id windowIamLookingFor;
  CFIndex index = CFArrayGetFirstIndexOfValue(mutWindowsIds, CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(window2ids)), (__bridge const void *)(windowIamLookingFor));
  CFArrayRemoveValueAtIndex(mutWindowsIds, index);
  CFRelease(mutWindowsIds);
```